# Unimodality of sequence

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have to show the following:
[image]

a) was pretty easy to show, however, I am not able to get something useful out of the recursive definition in b) and I have no idea how to approach c). What bijection are they talking about?
I would appreciate some hints regarding this task!
Thanks for your help

Comment: For 2, if you use induction, and just write out your recursion to compare 2 terms in row $n$ using those from row $n-1$,,it should follow almost right away.

Answer (score 1):

For (c) note that there is a bijection between subsets with $k$ elements and subsets with $n-k$ elements, simply by taking the complement of the subset. So assume $k < \lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$. Then by adding one extra element to each subset of size $k$ (i.e. for each choice of extra element,) you produce at least as many subsets (or more), because the maximum number of subsets of size $k$ that can lead to the same subset of size $k+1$ by adding one extra element is $k+1$, but for each subset of size $k$ you have at least $k+1$ (or more) extra elements that you can add to the set to produce a subset of size $k+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but I am still not really getting it. Why is the maximum number of subsets of size k that can lead to the same subset of size k+1 by adding one extra element k+1?
Sorry for my stupidity, I am new to combinatorics.